# Place instrumentation tests in feature modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, multi-module, android-instrumentation

I am having a multi-module architecture with an app module and feature/library modules.
Currently, there are some feature instrumentation tests in the app module. I would like to move instrumentation tests that test specific features in those respective feature modules under the `androidTest` folder. After some trial and error this is the state:

1. In app module gradle's file add

```
        androidTest {

            java.srcDirs += [
                    "${project(':feature').projectDir}/src/androidTest/kotlin"
            ]
            assets.srcDirs = [
                    "${project(':feature').projectDir}/src/androidTest/assets/",
            ]
        }
```

2. Created a "base-test" module where the base test classes are (BaseActivity and BaseUiTest)
3. In app and feature gradle file add

```
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

4. In app module's androidTest AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx">

    <application
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
        android:name=".App"
        android:label="Test app">
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I run the test from the android studio interface, the test is successful. However, when running the test from the command line (`./gradlew :feature:connectedAndroidTest`) the test fails due to app crashing at runtime (due to koin modules not being initialized - which they are at `CustomApplication's onCreate`)!

Even more weirdly, if I move the feature module's androidTest folder in its own module (e.g. feature-test module which depends on feature module) it works!

Is there any standardized way to put instrumented tests in each feature module in a multi-module setup? Why does from android studio run the test successfully but not from the command line?

Comment: What exactly means: "if I move the feature module's androidTest folder in its own module it works" - I thought it is a feature (sub) module? Where do you move it? I also saw that sometimes behavior from Terminal and Android Studio is different. Though for me it must run in terminal. If it does not in Android Studio I do not care. But yes, it should behave the same in both.

Comment: I meant if the androidTest folder is moved in its own module e.g. feature-test which depends on feature module

Answer (score 0):

with Gradle:

```bash
./gradlew :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.feature.ExampleActivityTest
```

with `adb`:

```bash
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class com.yourapp.feature.ExampleActivityTest yourApplicationId.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#run-tests-with-adb